# Do I need to tell tax office that I got £50 from yougov surveys?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, income

I got £50 from yougov few months before. Do I have to let the tax office know about it? I am getting tax credits as well.

Do I have to ring them about that £50 which I got from yougov surveys?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to declare it to HMRC. If you already fill in a tax return anyway then you can just declare it on there; if not, as you most likely don't, then you need to ring them to tell them.

Important note: telling the Tax Credits people is not sufficient. You also need to declare it to the Income Tax / Self Assessment people.

More information about how to do that is here: https://www.gov.uk/undeclared-income - broadly, they will ask you to register online and then fill in a declaration for any undeclared income for the last four years.

Answer (score 0):

This is income. It gets declared as such when you file your tax returns. Unless it affects your eligibility for the credits, you probably don't have to report it before then -- but you will get a more reliable answer about that if you tell us which country you are in.

Comment: My actual income is from my full time job. This is only once I have received  £50 from yougov. Yougov took my national insurance number as well. They must notify tax credit office. Do still i have to let tax office know about the  £50 or it's not a big deal if I don't notify the.

Comment: I need some more advice and information about this.

Comment: Any more answer about my question  ?

Comment: I'm not in the UK, but this should be exactly like any other small amount of income -- it doesn't matter if the government already knows about it or not, you have to list it on your tax return. I'm not sure what else you're asking....

Comment: @keshlam In the UK you don't normally do a tax return unless you are a high earner or have a more complex tax situation. It all gets sorted out through your employer.